# Why doesn't `tput` use my Terminfo file's data?

Tags: tty, terminfo

Ncurses programs insist on using only 80x24 on my text terminal that can show 132x50.
Why is that?  Where does `tput` find this info and how do I fix it?

```
% echo $LINES $COLUMNS
 
% tput -T hds3200-w50 cols
80
% tput -T hds3200-w50 lines
24
% infocmp hds3200-w50
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /home/monnier/.terminfo/h/hds3200-w50
hds3200-w50|Human Designed Systems HDS3200 model 20; VT220 7bits; 50x132; auto-wrap=no,
        mir, xenl, xon,
        cols#132, lines#50, vt#3,
        acsc=jjkkllmmnnqqttuuvvwwxx, bel=^G, blink=\E[5m$<2>,
        bold=\E[1m$<2>, civis=\E[?25l, clear=\E[H\E[2J$<50>,
        cnorm=\E[?25h, cr=\r, csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub1=^H,
        cud1=\E[B, cuf1=\E[C, cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH$<10>,
        cuu1=\E[A, dch1=\E[P, dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J$<50>, el=\E[K$<3>,
        home=\E[H, ht=^I, if=/usr/share/tabset/vt100, il1=\E[L,
        ind=\ED$<20/>, is2=\E[1;24r\E[24;1H, kbs=^H, kcmd=\E[17~,
        kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[B, kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A, kdl1=\E[3~,
        kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[11~, kf11=\E[12~, kf12=\E[13~,
        kf13=\E[14~, kf14=\E[15~, kf17=\E[18~, kf18=\E[19~,
        kf19=\E[20~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[21~, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS,
        kf6=\E[7~, kf7=\E[8~, kf8=\E[9~, kf9=\E[10~, kfnd=\E[1~,
        khlp=\E[16~, kil1=\E[2~, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, kslt=\E[4~,
        lf1=pf1, lf2=pf2, lf3=pf3, lf4=pf4, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m$<2>,
        rf=/usr/share/tabset/vt100, ri=\EM$<14/>,
        rmacs=\E(B$<4>, rmam=\E[?7l, rmir=\E[4l, rmso=\E[27m,
        rmul=\E[24m, rs2=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h,
        rs3=\E[?3h, sc=\E7,
        sgr=\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;m%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;,
        sgr0=\E[m$<2>, smacs=\E(0$<2>, smam=\E[?7h, smir=\E[4h,
        smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m,
%
```

As you can see, my Terminfo file specifies `cols#132` and `lines#50` yet `tput` seems to ignore those.  `strace` shows that `tput` does read my `~/.terminfo/h/hds3200-w50` as it should, yet it's not reflected in the output.

What am I doing wrong?  Where should I look?

Comment: Reported [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2023-06/msg00013.html), and answered.